# which Protocol to use to send mail(gmail) apart from SMTP

Tags: authentication

In my academic project , i have done work regarding generating OTP and sending it to the my Gmail account,i am using javaxmail.jar(SMTP port 587), am able to mail if i connect to internet using Dongle but the problem is in my college, college network blocks smtp protocol and i get error like "Must issue a STARTTLS command first. f13sm8890445pfj.35 - gsmtp", is there any other protocol that can be used?

If possible, can any one describe in detail.

Please help me regard this,this work is my academic project. 
I will be very much thank full for any reply

I have used java code to generate OTP, (SMTP PORT 578, even tried Port 465) javaxmail.jar to deliver Mail, eclipse IDE and apache tomcat server 7 and MYSQL database of XAMPP. (OS:windows 7)

work done:I have created Database which holds username,password,email Id which are entered through registration page(html) , which is linked to database and through Login page which ask for username & password when entered it ask to generete OTP, The OTP is sent to mail(Gmail Id entered in Registration page).

Since i am a student and i am not Knowledgeable to query in right way, if there is any fault in my query , i apologize for it.

Please Can I get Positive Reply for my Query, Kindly help me regarding this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use POP (Post Office Protocol)

Comment: @RachitPatel, sir can i get to know program that is available that use POP protocol to send mail to Gmail account? Can u post the Program or send me the link that consist the java Progrm

Comment: This is the program that i have used

Comment: I have used the code available in this url "http://crunchify.com/java-mailapi-example-send-an-email-via-gmail-smtp/" , with slight changes but used smtp port 587, now what changes i need to do , to send mail using POP Protocol